# Using pin and tween with ScrollMagic

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

I am working on a project where I need several divs to fly in and then pin to the screen while scrolling. I have tried adding the two together put it is causing the div to jump around strangely. Both pin and tween work perfectly alone but I cannot get them to work correctly together. Any suggestions? I have some code chunks below.

JQuery:

```
controller = new ScrollMagic();

var myTween = new TimelineMax()
    .add(TweenMax.to("#myTarget", .5, {
        top: "-=500"
        autoAlpha: 1,
        left: "+=300",
        color: "#aaaaaa"
    }));

new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "#myTrigger"})
    .setTween(myTween)
    .setPin('#myTarget')
    .addTo(controller);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myTrigger" class="space50"></div>
<div id="myTarget" class="label">Stuff</div>
```

CSS:

```
.space50 {
    height: 50px;
}
.label {
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good idea to animate a pin target. The reason is that there are many calculations taking place to make sure the element appears in the correct position during pin.
The simple solution is to make a wrapper around your element and pin it instead.
What happens inside of the wrapper (the animation) is seperate, so no problem. :)

For more help follow this guide: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md